# One-liner to convert and adjust a specified time in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, date

It's easy to accept a date in a specified but non-standard format (`date -j -f "EXISTING_DATE_FORMAT" "EXISTING_DATE" "OUTPUT_FORMAT"`), and easy to adjust a date with the same command (`date -j -v+1y "OUTPUT_FORMAT"`).

I have a date/time in a text string, that I need to convert (so `date` can understand it) and then adjust, before echoing it in a given format.

Unfortunately `date -j -v+1y -f "EXISTING_DATE_FORMAT" "EXISTING_DATE" "OUTPUT_FORMAT"` doesn't seem to be permitted, or at least isn't working for me. How can I get this effect?

Comment: Use a second `date` command inside `$(command substitution)` to convert from the existing format

Comment: Can you enter this as an answer (hopefully with a simple example to show the exact syntax)? Then I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry, I only commented, because I don't have a FreeBSD machine to verify.

Comment: Take the last example in the FreeBSD manual page for `date` as a further guide, and you can answer your own question.  (-: